How do I connect the Home, Shopping cart, and add to cart with each other?
I've been trying to direct the add to cart button on the home page of the website(for online shopping) to the addtocart file and the shopping cart. I just can't seem to find what's wrong. Here are the codes.
home.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>StyleSync Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo_no_name.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="shoppingcart.php">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                <li><a href="ootdposts.php">OOTD Posts</a></li>
                <li><a href="settings.php">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="faqs.php">FAQs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <main>
            <section class="banner">
                <div class="banner-content">
                    <h1>Welcome to Online Shopping!</h1>
                    <p>Discover the latest trends and exclusive deals.</p>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section class="featured-products">
                <h2>Featured Products</h2>
                <div class="product-card">
                    <img src="item1.jpg" alt="Product 1">
                    <h3>Product Name</h3>
                    <p>$99.99</p>
                    <form action="{{ route('addtocart') }}" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1">
                        <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- More product cards -->
            </section>
        </main>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-container">
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2024 Online Shopping. All rights reserved.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


shoppingcart.blade.php

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Shopping Cart Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleNavBar.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo_no_name.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route('shoppingcart') }}">Shopping Cart</a></li>  
                <li><a href="{{ route('OOTDposts') }}">OOTD Posts</a></li> 
                <li><a href="{{ route('settings') }}">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route('aboutus') }}">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ route('FAQs') }}">FAQs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>

    <div class="main-container">
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        <?php if (empty($cart)): ?>
            <p>Your cart is empty.</p>
        <?php else: ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($cart as $product_id => $quantity): ?>
                    <li>Product ID: <?php echo $product_id; ?> - Quantity: <?php echo $quantity; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


addtocart.blade.php
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

    // Initialize the cart if it doesn't exist
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'] = [];
    }

    // Add product to cart
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = 1;
    }

    // Redirect to shopping cart page
    header('Location: shoppingcart.php');
    exit;
}
?>


web.php

Route::get('/home',[HomeController::class, 'home'])->name('home');

Route::get('/shoppingcart', [CartController::class, 'showcart'])->name('shoppingcart');
Route::post('/addtocart', [CartController::class, 'addtocart'])->name('addtocart');


CartController
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function addtocart(Request $request)
    {
        $product_id = $request->input('product_id');
        
        $cart = session()->get('cart', []);

        if(isset($cart[$product_id])) {
            $cart[$product_id]++;
        } else {
            $cart[$product_id] = 1;
        }

        session(['cart' => $cart]);

        return redirect()->route('shoppingcart');
    }

    public function showcart()
    {
        $cart = session('cart', []);

        return view('shoppingcart', compact('cart'));
    }
}


Supposedly, when a user clicks the add to cart button on the home page, it redirects to the shopping cart page.

It looks like you're not taking advantage of Laravel's routes and controllers properly. Your form action is addtocart.php, which doesn't exist. Your actual route is /add-to-cart, as created in your web.php routes. You should have absolutely no cart logic in your blade files, it should be in the controller.

Laravel and other frameworks do not work like traditional PHP sites, there's a lot of functionality that you can take advantage of. I suggest looking into some good tutorials on how Laravel works, such as https://laracasts.com

this is hard :(

im gonna make some edits in the code

im still new at using laravel but im doing my best

"this is hard" - Funny that you say that about Laravel when it's designed to make working with PHP much easier  That being said, you need to have a pretty solid grasp of PHP Web Development and how Laravel is replacing that logic before you can use Laravel effectively. For example, you can use raw PHP in Laravel's .blade.php files, but there are replacements. <?php if (...) { ?> ... <?php } ?> can be written as @if(...) @endif. <?php foreach(...) { ?> <?php } ?> is @foreach(...) @endforeach, etc. Follow some tutorials, read some documentation, and you'll get the hang of it

Your form doesn't have the right action, it should use the route() helper:
<form action="{{ route('addtocart') }}" method="post">

addtocart.blade.php isn't needed because that's covered by the addtocart method in your CartController
And you can get rid of the session start part at the top of the shoppingcart.blade.php, because the framework already starts the session and you pass the $cart to the blade view.
The rest looks okay to me.
Documentation on the route helper

fyi, ->name('addtocart') the route name is addtocart

i took out the addtocart.blade.php on the views directory and replaced the actions in the home page. However, I made some edits a while ago so I don't know now if its still right. I'll edit the codes on the questions so that u can see the changes. Also, it says page expired when I click the add to cart haha

I've edited the codes in the question, hope u can help me again

@brombeer I edited that, but then went back and forth and forgot to edit it again. Thanks for the heads up!

@PENDONARAFAITH Add @csrf() on the line right after the form for add to cart opens. Should fix the 419 expired error.
